# Qual o uso apropriado do 'display: table'?

Tags: html, css, table

Como o próprio nome diz, o display `table` faz com que o elemento (divs, sections, etc.) tenha um comportamento bem semelhante a de uma tabela com a tag `<table>`, onde podemos usar elementos filhos com a propriedade `display: table-cell` que terão comportamento semelhante a células de uma `<table>`.

Por exemplo, posso usar a propriedade `vertical-align: middle;` numa div filha para centralizar verticalmente um conteúdo, como numa `<td>` de uma tabela `<table>`:

```css
.tabela{
   display: table;
   height: 200px;
   background: Yellow;
}

.celula{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabela">
   <div class="celula">
      Texto
   </div>
</div>
```

Minhas dúvidas:

É apropriado usar `display: table` para criar layouts ou deve ser usada apenas para criar tabelas, como faz a tag `<table>`?

Enfim, qual a aplicação apropriada dessa propriedade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O modelo de layout `table`, é apropriado para exibição de estrutura de dados tabulares, "*pois possuem uma estrutura interna [complexa](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#inner-model), com vários papéis diferentes que seus filhos e descendentes podem preencher*".

Ele se torna apropriado quando faz sentido, não faz sentido usá-lo em um elemento `img` apenas para fazer uso de propriedades de alinhamento, por exemplo.

Achei que uma resposta objetiva e com referências, fosse suficiente, talvez pela relação complexa embutida em seu interior o que segue abaixo seja necessário.

> ..."o display table faz com que o elemento (divs, sections, etc.) tenha um comportamento bem semelhante a de uma tabela com a tag `table`...

Quando diz semelhante, me passa a impressão de algo um tanto distante, entretanto é o comportamento de uma tabela.

[table](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-table)

> "O elemento gera uma wrapper box de tabela principal que estabelece um contexto de formatação de bloco e que contém um grid box de tabela gerada adicionalmente que estabelece um contexto de formatação de tabela."

Veja um pouco mais sobre a complexidade de modelos de layout:

> Alguns modelos de layout, como o table e o ruby , possuem uma estrutura interna complexa...
>
> ...
>   `box` com tipos de exibição específicos de layout geram wrapper box anônimas ao redor de si quando colocadas em um pai incompatível, conforme definido por suas respectivas especificações.
>
> Por exemplo, o layout de tabela requer que uma `table-cell` deva ter `table-row` como pai.
>
> Se for mal interpretado, assim:

```
<div style="display:block;">
    <div style="display:table-cell">...</div>
</div>
```

> Ele irá gerar wrapper box em torno de si, produzindo uma estrutura como:

```
block box
└anonymous table box
 └anonymous table-row-group box
  └anonymous table-row box
   └table-cell box
```

> Mesmo se o pai for outro elemento da tabela interna , se não for o correto , as wrapper box serão geradas.
>
> Esse "conserto" garante que o layout da tabela tenha uma estrutura previsível para operar.

Faz sentido... x)